# How to check if SQL column datatype is int and change if the condition is true

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sqldatatypes

I want to check if the SQL Server Compact column's datatype is `Int`, and if it is, change it to `Float`.

However I am just receiving this message that type is String, whereas the Column Number 7 "Amount" Type is INT.

I have not specified SQL query at the moment to change from INT to Float, I will add once the condition it picks up true and gets the right data type of that "Amount" Column which is INT right now.

```
private void CheckDataType()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Checking Data Type");
    string sqlcon = @"Data Source = .\Records.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";

    using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(sqlcon))
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"Select data_type
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = 'OutgoingChequeRecords' and column_name = 'Amount'", conn);

        SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                  
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Reading Started");

            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Type dataType = reader.GetFieldType(i);
                string columnName = reader.GetName(i); 

                if (dataType == typeof(int))
                {
                    // Do for integers (INT, SMALLINT, BIGINT)
                    MessageBox.Show("Type is INT");
                }
                else if (dataType == typeof(double))
                {
                    // Do for doubles (DOUBLE, DECIMAL)
                    MessageBox.Show("Type is Decimal");
                }
                else if (dataType == typeof(string))
                {
                    // Do for Strings (VARCHAR, NVARCHAR).
                    MessageBox.Show("Type is String");
                }
                else if (dataType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    // Do for DateTime (DATETIME)
                    MessageBox.Show("Type is DateTime");
                }
                else if (dataType == typeof(byte[]))
                {
                    // Do for Binary (BINARY, VARBINARY, NVARBINARY, IMAGE)
                    MessageBox.Show(columnName);
                }
               
                else if (dataType == typeof(float))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Type is Float");
                }    
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Reading Stopped, Connection Closed");

        conn.Close();
    }   
}
```

[Type is String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhv9C.png)

Comment: Please share a CREATE TABLE statement

Comment: use a switch case!

Comment: @ErikEJ Table already exists, I am checking cases.

Comment: The actual data type of `data_type` in `information_schema.columns` will always be a string of the name of the data type for that column. So you can just output that string. You should really use `sys.columns` instead, because `information_schema.columns` is for compatibility only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply run `(string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` and check its value is `"int"`. I am assuming there is only one column with the same table name across all schemas. If there are more then you can add the scheme as well in condition `TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourSchema'`

Comment: I have 08 columns and its SQL Compact, the corresponding column is "Amount" which is int that I need to change it to float if its int.

Comment: I think your solution is working, I am testing.

Comment: @NewDeveloper I think my answer has answered your original question, is it? Changing the type is different question. You can ask new question

Comment: Your solution is working:  however there is one issue, I am getting string of type code how can I convert this string back to type code so I can use my switch cases above?

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. Your answer works with string but it doesnt get data type, my work still is done.

Comment: @NewDeveloper you haven’t

Comment: My reputation is less, but my feedback has been recorded. "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @NewDeveloper you can accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check this way

```
Type type = reader.GetFieldType(i);

switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
{
    case TypeCode.DateTime:
        break;
    case TypeCode.String:
        break;
    default: break;
}
```

Comment: it breaks at string. My column "Amount" type is Int.

Comment: have you crosschecked in database, if possible can you print columnname and type to get whole picture clear?